# [TypeError: hex is not a function]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Code:

```
jwt.verify(token,JWT_SECRET,(err,payload)=>{
    if(err){
        res.status(401).json({error:"You must be logged in"})
    }
    const _id = payload._id
    collection_name.findById(_id)
    .then(userdata=>{
        req.user = payload
        next()
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

error received:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5f5a5cc2b2dd9f0e50788fd8" at path "_id" for model "model_name"]
```

> messageFormat: undefined,
> stringValue: '"5f5a5cc2b2dd9f0e50788fd8"',
> kind: 'ObjectId',
> value: '5f5a5cc2b2dd9f0e50788fd8',
> path: '_id',
> **reason: [TypeError: hex is not a function]** }

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search string id (payload._id) in MongoDB(_id),

You will need to convert string id to object id before searching

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(payload._id)
```

Comment: Still i'm getting an error of hex is not a function

Comment: you are using mongo driver or mongoose?

Comment: i am using mongoose

Comment: **TypeError: hex is not a function**

Comment: still getting this only

Comment: Never mind. Mine was an issue with the update of node.js. It's updated now and works fine. Thanks for the help btw.